# How to install Ranorex studio in ubuntu (linux)

Tags: mobile-automation, ranorex, ubuntu

Ranorex studio is an automation tool but i can only install in windows how to install in ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Ranorex is a Windows **only** application thus you cannot install it on Linux or macOS.

You could install Windows in a virtual machine, for example with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and the [free 90 day testing images of Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). Now you can install Ranorex in the virtual machine.